# Invoking Tibco Web Service Using JMS

Tags: java, web-services, jms, tibco

I have created and deployed a web service in tibco that use a JMS Connection,

I want to get a java class to connect to the tibco ems server and communicate with that service, using JMS.

is that possible ? how would I proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's possible... You need to provide more information about the use case and the tools you are using here but all you have to do is to use a JMS request-reply client listening to the queue/topic where you receive the message from the Web Service. The nature of the request/reply JMS pattern is to consume the message, process it and then reply back with the response. This is pretty straightforward with TIBCO BusinessWorks. Have a look on the examples folder as it contains many pre-defined samples you can use as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is to invoke a SOAP Service over JMS.

This is possible in Java and has been discussed [here](http://www.eaipatterns.com/RequestReplyJmsExample.html) in general. Change the data to have a SOAP request and you have your answer.

You can also find multiple examples of how this is done by doing a Google Search for the same ( request reply jms ) . If you want examples of EMS, combine the above with the examples already provided by TIBCO.

TIBCO EMS provides an example for [request reply](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/6.0.1_january_2011/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/javadoc/index.html?javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html).

Answer (score -1):

You lost me a bit when you say "communicate with that web service using JMS".

Typically you communicate with web service over HTTP protocol. JMS is the messaging API typically used to queue incoming web service request for processing.

From what I understand, what you wanted to do is to build a webservice client that connect to your Tibco Web Service?

If so, yes this is possible, Java EE come with web service API you can use. Web service chapter on Java EE tutorial is a good place to start: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html

Comment: I want to create a class that send an SOAP request and waits for a reply, this web service is created in tibco and communicating over JMS.